# Is it always safe to use WITH SCHEMABINDING in a UDF?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016

SO I have been reading about `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and how it can improve the performance of queries using a scalar UDF by omitting the table spool operator from the execution plan. I think I understand halloween protection.

My question is: If I add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to a UDF used in a SP is it possible that a SP does not give the same results? If yes in what scenario?

Comment: Please check this --> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1692/using-schema-binding-to-improve-sql-server-udf-performance/

Comment: Also: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/ and also consider null on null input : https://sqlperformance.com/2018/12/sql-performance/improve-udfs-null-on-null-input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact it's the other way around. If you check the [Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#best-practices) section of the CREATE FUNCTION doc, you'll see that:

> If a user-defined function is not created with the SCHEMABINDING
> clause, changes that are made to underlying objects can affect the
> definition of the function and produce unexpected results when it is
> invoked. We recommend that you implement one of the following methods
> to ensure that the function does not become outdated because of
> changes to its underlying objects:
>
> - Specify the WITH SCHEMABINDING clause when you are creating the    function. This ensures that the objects referenced in the function
>   definition cannot be modified unless the function is also modified.